# модель с сообщениями и диалогами

Tags: python, django

Как создать модель с сообщениями и диалогами, чтобы у пользователя был список диалогов, а в каждом диалоге переписка с юзером? Я пробовал сделать так:

**models.py**

```
    class Message(models.Model):
        sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender",on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,)
        reciever = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="reciever",on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,) 
        msg_content = models.TextField(null='True')
        class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = "Postings"
```

**views.py**

```
    def message(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            pass
        else:
            user_list = []
            user_list2 = {}
            user_list_update = {}
            new_user_list = []
            obj_profil_avas = []
            messag_list = Message.objects.filter(Q(reciever=request.user) | Q(sender=request.user))
            for xx in messag_list:
                user_list.append(xx)
            for user_list_chek1 in user_list:
                user_list2.update({user_list_chek1.id: [user_list_chek1.reciever.id, user_list_chek1.sender.id]})
            data = {v: k for k, v in {tuple(sorted(v)): k for k, v in reversed(user_list2.items())}.items()}
            for new_data_keys, new_data_values in zip(data.keys(), data.values()):
                values_d1 = new_data_values[0]
                values_d2 = new_data_values[1]
                if request.user.id == values_d1:
                    print("v1==",values_d1)
                    user_list_update.update({new_data_keys:[values_d2, values_d1]})
                else:
                    print("no ==")
                    user_list_update.update({new_data_keys:[values_d1, values_d2]})
            print("user_list_update:",user_list_update)

            for new_data_messga_keys, new_data_messga_value in zip(user_list_update.keys(), user_list_update.values()):
                new_user_list.append(Message.objects.get(id=new_data_messga_keys))
                obj_profil_avas.append(Profilava.objects.get(user=new_data_messga_value[0]))
            useer_message_ava_list = zip(new_user_list, obj_profil_avas)
            print()
            return render(request, 'board/message.html', {'useer_message_ava_list':useer_message_ava_list})
    else:
        return redirect('login')

    def message_id(request, id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            message_form = MessageForm(request.POST)
            if message_form.is_valid(): 
                messag_forma = (message_form.cleaned_data['messages_name'])
                users_id = User.objects.get(id=id)
                Message.objects.create(reciever=users_id, sender=request.user, msg_content=messag_forma)

            return redirect(f'/message/{id}')
        else:
            test = Message.objects.all()
            message_form = MessageForm(request.POST)
            message_list = []
            objs_list_user_ava = []
            for chek1 in test:
                if chek1.sender == request.user:
                    if chek1.reciever.id == id:
                        entries = (chek1.msg_content, "вы",request.user)
                        #message_list.append(entries)
                        message_list.append(chek1)
                        objs_list_user_ava.append(Profilava.objects.get(user=request.user))  ### если фото в диалоге не правильно оботражаются то поменять  user=id на user=request.user
                if chek1.reciever == request.user:
                    if chek1.sender.id == id:
                        entries = (chek1.msg_content, "от",chek1.sender)
                        #message_list.append(entries)
                        message_list.append(chek1)
                        objs_list_user_ava.append(Profilava.objects.get(user=id))  ## и тут тоже
            data_user_fs = zip(message_list, objs_list_user_ava)
            return render(request, 'board/message_id.html', {'dialoge_list':data_user_fs, 'message_form':message_form})
    else:
        return redirect('login')
```

Функция *message* выводит список диалогов с кем начата переписка, а функция *message_id* выводит всю переписку в диалоге.

C такой моделью неудобно сортировать сообщения и делить их на диалоги. Оптимизировать код нельзя — это создаст кучу нагрузки.

Comment: Если вы не начнете пользоваться пунктуацией и проверкой орфографии вместо украшательства сообщения болдом, я буду голосовать за закрытие ваших вопросов, как написанных  не на русском языке.